# How to get separate analysers in wavesurfer to process stereo channels

Tags: web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I'm using wavesurfer.js in a react app to play audio files and I want to get the frequency data for each stereo channel independently so I can implement stereo VU meters.

I'm using the audioprocess event of an wavesurfer instance as shown below.

```
const player = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#sound',
  waveColor: 'blue',
  progressColor: 'white'
});

const analyser = player.backend.analyser;

player.on('audioprocess', (data) => {
  let frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
  console.log("PLAYER FREQ DATA [0]...[n]", frequencyData.length, getAverageVolume(frequencyData));
});
```

This works ok, but appears to be the frequency response for both channels. How can I get two analysers with each being just one of the stereo channels.